# vector float to int/sign conversion

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector

```
vector<float>v = {-0.2f, 1.4f, -6.5f};
```

I like it gets converted to

```
v = {-1, 1, -1};
```

The logic is: for each element, if it is less than 0, then set to -1, if it is equal to 0, then set it to 0, if it is greater than 0, then set it to 1.

Comment: [This looks like a job for `std::transform`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: @XinHuang please dont be a victim of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to do your comparisons and replace the elements accordingly.

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](float f)
{
    return f == 0 ? 0 : (f < 0 ? -1 : 1);
});
```

Comment: Whenever you compare a float with a zero using == a kitten dies somewhere on the other side of the globe

Comment: @XinHuang your comparison will cause confusing result because using your sign negative * negative can be negative and negative*positive can be positive according to your definition

Comment: @tomdol Except for the time that you want to know if a value is exactly equal to `0.0`.... which is exactly what the OP asked. So your point is?

Comment: @tomdol there is only a single number that is on the edge of being negative and being positive, not a range of numbers, using an epislon is actually wrong here

Comment: @XinHuang Aside from the other comment, your suggestion is actually plain wrong since you need to scale the `epsilon()` - For a 32-bits float on IEEE754, epsilon is 0.00000011920928955078125, which is the value represented by the last bit of the mantissa, except that this can be scaled down up to `2^-128` by the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to avoid equality operator:

```
std::vector<float> in{-0.4, 0.0, 5.0001};
std::vector<int> out;
out.reserve(in.size());

std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), [](float n) {
    return (n > 0.0) - (n < 0.0);
});
```

Comment: What's the point? This code is equivalent to CoryKramer one... Blindlessly avoiding using `==` between floating point numbers for the sake of avoiding it is pointless.

Comment: @user463035818 I was refering to the *"There's an easy way to avoid equality operator:"*, but thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: imho it is misleading that you write "to avoid the equality operator", because the equality operator isnt really the point. You could add using a call to the equality operator, but it would still be better in terms of not using jumps: https://godbolt.org/g/fZjVEE. That being said, I would always go for clarity and readability (ie if i want to compare for equality to zero i'd write `n==0`) and let the compiler do its job